# How do I open the root.disk in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wubi

When doing a wubi install of linux from windows, the place/file where all linux info is saved is inside a "root.disk" file.

I am intending on formatting my laptop to run linux only and I can't seem to find a way to open this root.disk file from linux itself (to extract some of the files from my previous installation). Of course, it does and is able to open in windows using a certain software, but because I will only have linux on my system now, does anybody know how to open this file in linux itself? It's kind of strange that it isn't able to open with the default linux tools.

Specs:

I am using Linux Mint 12 (via wubi install). Intending on moving to a 'lighter' version of linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mount this image before you can access it, try the following:

```
mkdir olddisk
sudo mount -o loop /path/to/root.disk olddisk
```

You should now be able to access the data inside this container.

Comment: By mounting it, will I be installing/placing the disk onto the system?

Comment: No, you can unmmount it after you copied over the files you need. Your actual system won´t be changed.

Comment: Thanks flo, it worked as you said. I had to run the script in the root folder (the 1 that opens up when you open terminal/console). Also, to unmount, I used "umount /path/to/root.disk olddisk", but do you know why it was still showing under "Devices" in the file manager?